# Python 3 Attribute Error: Statsmodels has no attribute 'tools'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels

Im trying to use the following code (example):

```
import pandas as pd
(import statsmodels.api as sm) - Tried adding, no luck
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf

x = pd.DataFrame(imports a vector)
plot_acf(x)
```

There is some code in between, but the problem arises when Python tries to plot the autocorrelation using statsmodels, and returns the following error:

```
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/statsmodels/iolib/foreign.py",
line 20, in <module>
import statsmodels.tools.data as data_util

AttributeError: module 'statsmodels' has no attribute 'tools'
```

I tried reinstalling multiple libraries, but nothing seems to get me past this error. Could this be a statsmodels-side bug?

Comment: which os are you using? did you try reinstall it?

Comment: Is your own script called "statsmodels.py"? If so you should rename it.

Comment: MacOS. The file has a different name.